# Save d3js dynamically generated svg chart to png directly on server side

Tags: c#-4.0, svg, d3.js, png

I am generating a d3js graph dynamically which gives me a svg. I want to save this svg to png directly on the server without installing anything on the server. 
I am using C# on the server.

I am using svgenie to convert svg to png but it opens the png in a new window. Can anyone tell me how can I save it directly on the server.

Comment: If you search SO, you'll find a number of server-side solutions for doing this, mostly with node.js or similar. How do those solutions not work for you?

Comment: In addition Lars comment there has been a recent discussion on the d3 Google groups page about this.

Comment: @user1614080 can you please give me the link

Comment: It's pretty easy to find (such search for google groups d3.js) but here it is anyway: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/qQN1yb6XQcI).  There's also a link to the GG from the [D3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) as well as other useful resources.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but phantomJS will allow you to do this. It enables you to render the chart on the server and then convert that to an image.